# JSF JDBC Jasper Reports

Tags: jsf, pdf, jsf-2, jasper-reports, report

I need to have some sort of a reporting tool that can generate PDF reports (data coming from a database) that will be used in my jsf application.

The one that i have heard is Jasper Reports.

I am wondering if it possible to use raw JDBC to work with Jasper? If so, could someone direct me to some tutorials? All the ones i fine are based on JPA.

Also are there any other good reporting tools that can be integrated with JSF?

Thanks

Comment: `if it possible to use raw JDBC to work with Jasper?` - yes. Look at [JasperReports - Sample Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can use JasperReport in JSF, is very good. I suggest as a tool iReport report designer. You must include the iText library in your project.

2 - The report have two ways of filling, from the database values ​​or injecting it in memory.

3 - You can also generate reports through a Primefaces data exporter, so you can build the document at runtime.

Comment: wait with the dataexporter, can i make some sort of design with it?

Comment: the dataexporter is basically to export a table, but you can design and manipulate as you would exit the export.
If it is a pdf, you can add anything to pdf using itext.
(see this book: Bruno Lowagie - iText in Action), is very easy.
Can adding thereto images, paragraphs, tables ... this way you complement on the benefits of using the methods dataexporter preprocessor and postprocessor.